# How to create values on new colum based on other columns?

Tags: r

My initial data

```
test = structure(list(sex = c("M", "F", "F", "F", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M"), id = c("903809", "903868", "904904", "904904", 
"904904", "903868", "903818", "903841", "903868", "903818"), 
    value = c(1.2, 200, 2.16, 0.5, 4.35, 198, 202.3, 88.4, 90.8, 
    235.5)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

my desired output

```
test = structure(list(sex = c("M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M"), 
               id = c("903809", "903868", "904904", "904904", "904904", "903868", "903818", "903841", "903868", "903818"), 
               value = c(1.2, 200, 2.16, 0.5, 4.35, 198, 202.3, 88.4, 90.8, 235.5), 
               status = c("INVALID", "INVALID", "INVALID", "VALID", "VALID", "INVALID", "VALID", "INVALID", "VALID", "VALID")), 
          row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

This should be easy but im struggling:
I require to run some validations based on the `value` and `sex` colum. With the code i currently have, the next `ifelse` will delete (`""`) what i have done before. Im not sure on how not to do anything on the `NO` portion of the ifelse.

```
test$status = ifelse( (test$id== "904904") & (test$sex == "F") & (test$value > 2) , 
                                  'INVALID', 
                                  ifelse( (test$id == "904904") & (test$sex == "M") & (test$value > 6) ,
                                          'INVALID', 
                                          ifelse(test$id == "904904",
                                                 'VALID' ,
                                                 "" )))


test$status = ifelse( (test$id== "903809") & (test$value <= 1.1) , 
                                  'VALID', 
                                  ifelse(test$id == "903809", 
                                         'INVALID' , 
                                         ''))


test$status = ifelse( (test$id== "903818") & (test$value > 200) , 
                                'VALID', 
                                ifelse(test$id == "903818", 
                                       'INVALID' , 
                                       ''))

test$status = ifelse( (test$id== "903841") & (test$value > 70) & (test$value < 85) , 
                      'VALID', 
                      ifelse(test$id == "903841", 
                             'INVALID' , 
                             ''))


test$status = ifelse( (test$id== "903868") & (test$value < 150)  , 
                      'VALID', 
                      ifelse(test$id == "903868", 
                             'INVALID' , 
                             ''))
```

Comment: Can you also include your final expected results?

Comment: Sure! Give me a minute

Comment: Done. Please see edit

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you have mutated new column `status` multiple times.  If your conditions do not follow any pattern you have to use multiple nesting like this, where you want to `do nothing` actually.

**Advise use `dplyr::case_when` in such cases**

```
test$status = ifelse( (test$id== "904904") & (test$sex == "F") & (test$value > 2) , 
                      'INVALID', 
                      ifelse( (test$id == "904904") & (test$sex == "M") & (test$value > 6) ,
                              'INVALID', 
                              ifelse(test$id == "904904",
                                     'VALID' ,
                                     ifelse( (test$id== "903809") & (test$value <= 1.1) , 
                                             'VALID', 
                                             ifelse(test$id == "903809", 
                                                    'INVALID' , 
                                                    ifelse( (test$id== "903818") & (test$value > 200) , 
                                                            'VALID', 
                                                            ifelse(test$id == "903818", 
                                                                   'INVALID' , 
                                                                   ifelse( (test$id== "903841") & (test$value > 70) & (test$value < 85) , 
                                                                           'VALID', 
                                                                           ifelse(test$id == "903841", 
                                                                                  'INVALID' , 
                                                                                  ifelse( (test$id== "903868") & (test$value < 150)  , 
                                                                                          'VALID', 
                                                                                          ifelse(test$id == "903868", 
                                                                                                 'INVALID' , 
                                                                                                 ''))
                                                                                  ))
                                                                   ))
                                                    ))
                                     )
                              ))

test
   sex     id  value  status
1    M 903809   1.20 INVALID
2    F 903868 200.00 INVALID
3    F 904904   2.16 INVALID
4    F 904904   0.50   VALID
5    M 904904   4.35   VALID
6    M 903868 198.00 INVALID
7    M 903818 202.30   VALID
8    M 903841  88.40 INVALID
9    M 903868  90.80   VALID
10   M 903818 235.50   VALID
```

---

`dplyr` way that's a lot less typing

```
test %>%
  mutate(status = case_when((id== "904904") & (sex == "F") & (value > 2) ~ 'INVALID',
                            (id == "904904") & (sex == "M") & (value > 6) ~ 'INVALID',
                            (id== "903809") & (value > 1.1) ~ 'INVALID',
                            (id== "903818") & (value <= 200) ~ 'INVALID',
                            id== "903841" & (value <= 70 | value >= 85) ~ 'INVALID',
                            id== "903868" & value >= 150 ~ 'INVALID',
                            TRUE ~ 'VALID'
                            ))

   sex     id  value  status
1    M 903809   1.20 INVALID
2    F 903868 200.00 INVALID
3    F 904904   2.16 INVALID
4    F 904904   0.50   VALID
5    M 904904   4.35   VALID
6    M 903868 198.00 INVALID
7    M 903818 202.30   VALID
8    M 903841  88.40 INVALID
9    M 903868  90.80   VALID
10   M 903818 235.50   VALID
```

or even lesser without using case_when

```
test %>%
  mutate(status = c('VALID', 'INVALID')[ 1 + ((id== "904904" & sex == "F" & value > 2) |
                              (id == "904904" & sex == "M" & value > 6) | 
                              (id== "903809" & value > 1.1) | 
                              (id== "903818" & value <= 200) | 
                              (id== "903841" & (value <= 70 | value >= 85)) |
                              (id== "903868" & value >= 150))])

   sex     id  value  status
1    M 903809   1.20 INVALID
2    F 903868 200.00 INVALID
3    F 904904   2.16 INVALID
4    F 904904   0.50   VALID
5    M 904904   4.35   VALID
6    M 903868 198.00 INVALID
7    M 903818 202.30   VALID
8    M 903841  88.40 INVALID
9    M 903868  90.80   VALID
10   M 903818 235.50   VALID
```

Comment: Interesting. So multiple nested ifelse. Would this impact a long dataframe (40k rows)?.  Do you think `dplyr::case_when` can be more efficient in terms of coding and indentation?

Comment: @AndresMora If your conditions follow a pattern you can use multiple alternate ways.  one is to use `joins`, but if not I am not sure how I will impact performance

Comment: Thanks. Ive been considering multiple joins but that would require multiple temporary tables

Comment: @AndresMora, 2 more strategies include that require very less typing

Answer (score 3):

Here's a method that uses `merge`. My premise for suggesting it is twofold:

1. maintaining that many nested `ifelse` is hard to read, easy to get something wrong, and does not scale well at all; this is mitigated slightly by the suggestion to use `case_when`, but not completely; and
2. it allows you to keep an unambiguous dictionary of limits for each id/sex combination. I believe many people find comfort in maintaining this validation frame in a separate CSV, easily viewable and editable (perhaps in Excel or Calc).

First, we'll create a frame of valid values, where `NA` means "no limit":

```r
validation <- read.csv(text = "
id,sex,func,limit
904904,F,<=,2
904904,M,<=,6
903809,,<=,1.1
903818,,>,200
903841,,>,70
903841,,<,85
903868,,<,150", na.strings = "")
validation
#       id  sex func limit
# 1 904904    F   <=   2.0
# 2 904904    M   <=   6.0
# 3 903809 <NA>   <=   1.1
# 4 903818 <NA>    > 200.0
# 5 903841 <NA>    >  70.0
# 6 903841 <NA>    <  85.0
# 7 903868 <NA>    < 150.0
```

Note that two or more `id`/`sex` rows are permitted, and they will be logically `AND`ed.

The validation `func` supports any infix (binary) operator that returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` given two vectors.

Now, because we are using `merge` (which doesn't take an `NA` sex as "merge either"), we need to split into two separate frames for merging once with id/sex and again with just id. I suggest that you only worry about maintaining the frame above, and let the code below handle the separation and merging.

```r
validation_withsex <- subset(validation, !is.na(sex))
validation_withoutsex <- subset(validation, is.na(sex), select = -sex)
```

From there, let's merge. We do two merges and row-bind them. This results in several rows for each id/sex combination, some with matches, some without matches. *This is okay*. However, in order to prepare for the last step (which is summarizing all "valid" claims into a single claim for each row), we'll store the row numbers in `test`.

```r
test$rownum <- seq_len(nrow(test)) # so we can aggregate VALID checks
tmp <- rbind(
  merge(test, validation_withsex, by = c("id", "sex"), all.x = TRUE),
  merge(test, validation_withoutsex, by = "id", all.x = TRUE)
)
tmp$func[is.na(tmp$func)] <- "skip"
tmp
#        id sex  value rownum func limit
# 1  903809   M   1.20      1 skip    NA
# 2  903818   M 202.30      7 skip    NA
# 3  903818   M 235.50     10 skip    NA
# 4  903841   M  88.40      8 skip    NA
# 5  903868   F 200.00      2 skip    NA
# 6  903868   M  90.80      9 skip    NA
# 7  903868   M 198.00      6 skip    NA
# 8  904904   F   2.16      3   <=   2.0
# 9  904904   F   0.50      4   <=   2.0
# 10 904904   M   4.35      5   <=   6.0
# 11 903809   M   1.20      1   <=   1.1
# 12 903818   M 202.30      7    > 200.0
# 13 903818   M 235.50     10    > 200.0
# 14 903841   M  88.40      8    >  70.0
# 15 903841   M  88.40      8    <  85.0
# 16 903868   F 200.00      2    < 150.0
# 17 903868   M 198.00      6    < 150.0
# 18 903868   M  90.80      9    < 150.0
# 19 904904   M   4.35      5 skip    NA
# 20 904904   F   2.16      3 skip    NA
# 21 904904   F   0.50      4 skip    NA
```

NB: I explicitly set `NA`s found in `func` to be a reserved word `"skip"`. The use of `by(.)` below does not deal with `NA`s correctly in grouping, so I needed something non-NA.

From here, we can do a single validation for all rows at the same time:

```r
tmp <- do.call(rbind, by(tmp, list(tmp$func), FUN = function(x) {
  if (x$func[1] == "skip") return(transform(x, valid = TRUE))
  transform(x, valid = is.na(value) | is.na(limit) |
                 match.fun(x$func[1])(value, limit))
}))
tmp$valid <- ave(tmp$valid, tmp[,"rownum"], FUN = all)
tmp$func <- tmp$limit <- NULL
tmp
#             id sex  value rownum valid
# <.15    903841   M  88.40      8 FALSE
# <.16    903868   F 200.00      2 FALSE
# <.17    903868   M 198.00      6 FALSE
# <.18    903868   M  90.80      9  TRUE
# <=.8    904904   F   2.16      3 FALSE
# <=.9    904904   F   0.50      4  TRUE
# <=.10   904904   M   4.35      5  TRUE
# <=.11   903809   M   1.20      1 FALSE
# >.12    903818   M 202.30      7  TRUE
# >.13    903818   M 235.50     10  TRUE
# >.14    903841   M  88.40      8 FALSE
# skip.1  903809   M   1.20      1 FALSE
# skip.2  903818   M 202.30      7  TRUE
# skip.3  903818   M 235.50     10  TRUE
# skip.4  903841   M  88.40      8 FALSE
# skip.5  903868   F 200.00      2 FALSE
# skip.6  903868   M  90.80      9  TRUE
# skip.7  903868   M 198.00      6 FALSE
# skip.19 904904   M   4.35      5  TRUE
# skip.20 904904   F   2.16      3 FALSE
# skip.21 904904   F   0.50      4  TRUE
```

This is a little more complex than it strictly needs to be, but that is for a reason: this preserves as much vectorization as possible. Lacking grouping by `func`, we'd need to do singular comparisons for each row, which will scale very poorly (if your data is not-small).

Finally, we aggregate each `rownum` (which inherently preserves id/sex):

```r
out <- do.call(rbind, by(tmp, list(tmp$rownum), head, n = 1))
out$rownum <- NULL
out
#        id sex  value valid
# 1  903809   M   1.20 FALSE
# 2  903868   F 200.00 FALSE
# 3  904904   F   2.16 FALSE
# 4  904904   F   0.50  TRUE
# 5  904904   M   4.35  TRUE
# 6  903868   M 198.00 FALSE
# 7  903818   M 202.30  TRUE
# 8  903841   M  88.40 FALSE
# 9  903868   M  90.80  TRUE
# 10 903818   M 235.50  TRUE
```

and you can `ifelse(valid, "VALID", "INVALID")` if you really prefer it to be a string vice a `logical`.

You can clean all of these operations into a single convenience function:

```r
func <- function(x, validation) {
  validation_withsex <- subset(validation, !is.na(sex))
  validation_withoutsex <- subset(validation, is.na(sex), select = -sex)

  test$rownum <- seq_len(nrow(test)) # so we can aggregate VALID checks
  tmp <- rbind(
    merge(test, validation_withsex, by = c("id", "sex"), all.x = TRUE),
    merge(test, validation_withoutsex, by = "id", all.x = TRUE)
  )
  tmp$func[is.na(tmp$func)] <- "skip"

  tmp <- do.call(rbind, by(tmp, list(tmp$func), FUN = function(x) {
    if (x$func[1] == "skip") return(transform(x, valid = TRUE))
    transform(x, valid = is.na(value) | is.na(limit) |
                   match.fun(x$func[1])(value, limit))
  }, simplify = TRUE))
  tmp$valid <- ave(tmp$valid, tmp[,"rownum"], FUN = all)
  tmp$func <- tmp$limit <- NULL

  out <- do.call(rbind, by(tmp, list(tmp$rownum), head, n = 1))
  out$rownum <- NULL
  out
}

func(test, validation)
#        id sex  value valid
# 1  903809   M   1.20 FALSE
# 2  903868   F 200.00 FALSE
# 3  904904   F   2.16 FALSE
# 4  904904   F   0.50  TRUE
# 5  904904   M   4.35  TRUE
# 6  903868   M 198.00 FALSE
# 7  903818   M 202.30  TRUE
# 8  903841   M  88.40 FALSE
# 9  903868   M  90.80  TRUE
# 10 903818   M 235.50  TRUE
```